# Python Ft.Xml.cDomlette.Element toxml/tostring?

Tags: python, xml

In a large Python application I have an instance of `Ft.Xml.cDomlette.Element` that I need to turn back into an XML string (as close to the original as possible).

In existing code we're doing the following:

```
PrettyPrint(element, stream=buff, encoding="utf8")
```

However, depending on the current element this can produce XML that is very far from the original.

Example:

Original XML:

```
<use id="Geneve" x="499500" y="181000" xlink:href="#symbolRect"/>
```

`PrettyPrint` of `Element`:

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xlink:actuate="onLoad" xlink:show="embed" 
    xlink:href="#symbolRect" y="181000"
    xlink:type="simple" x="499500" id="Geneve"/>
```

The namespace stuff doesn't bother me, it's easy enough to remove. It's the odd addition of the other attributes that is worrisome.  Any ideas on how to get a closer representation of the original XML?

Comment: Please provide sample code and xml. The only extra attribute I get is xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink". You can also try stepping through the code in Ft.Xml.Lib.PrintVisitor.visitElement to see where the additional attrs are coming from.